# Call function from autosize.js to update swiper.js

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I’m looking for a way to update [swiper.js](http://idangero.us/swiper/) from autosize.js (old version).

*In more detail:*

I have an autosize textarea within the swiper. The swiper is set to autoheight. This means that the textarea is within a swiper slide that is set to `overflow:hidden`. Now, when the textarea is changing height the slide height isn't changing, and because of the `overflow:hidden` part of my content is cut off.

To solve this I want to update de slide height when the height of the textarea is changed.

In the autosize.js plugin there is a part (from line 178) where the height is set:

```
 if (original !== height) {
     ta.style.height = height + 'px';
     if (callback) {
         options.callback.call(ta,ta);
     }

     /* send trigger to update slide here */
 }
```

When this part is happening I want to send a trigger outside the plugin to update the swiper slide. I have a function (nothing fancy) for this.

```
function updateSwiper(){
    mySwiper.update();
}
```

Both plugins and the custom function (above) are in the same file.

So now I am wondering, how can I solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you cant find it because its a bit bizarre. A plugin should be a self-contained unit of work. By calling to an external function from within the plugin you're breaking the encapsulation.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) We cannot help you with code we cannot see. Please update the question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem. In general, calling functions in an outer scope from an inner scope is quite simple: You just call them.

Comment: Consider passing *in* a function pointer and executing it at the appropriate time. When you set up your plugin this callback function can be a call to your external functionality.

Comment: Ah okay that explains, what I want is to call a function evertime a value in the plugin is changed. Is this possible? Is it possible to output the value from the plugin and track that?

Comment: *Anything* is possible in a plugin. You need to update your question with some relevant code, and explain exactly what it is you want to do - as it stands your question is too broad. Read @T.J.Crowder comment.

Comment: Sorry, I updated/rewrote my question. I some times have te feeling that asking a broad question is more useful for others. But I understand that narrowing it down is easier to answer, so read the result at the top.

Comment: Ive checked out your update - and line 178 of autosize.js looks nothing like the code you posted (nor can I find any code which does!). In any case it looks like autosize does raise an event when it is resized so you should be able to hook in to that if you want to perform some action when the textarea resizes. Cant really help much more at the moment - still dont really know what you're trying to do. Provide a [mcve] if you want more help.

Comment: Sorry, I see the file on github is changed. I'll update my question again.

Answer (score 0):

Out of all comments my research ended in finding out that I'm using an old version of autosize.js. The new version has a trigger for when the height of a textarea is changed. As can be read in this documentation: [Autosize Documentation](http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/)

To solve this in jQuery you can use this piece of code:

```
$('textarea').each(function(){
  autosize(this);
}).on('autosize:resized', function(){
  console.log('textarea height updated');
});
```

This code first sets autosize to a textarea and uses a `on('autosize.resized')` to track if the height is changed.

Updating this code to my version:

```
 $('textarea').each(function(){
   autosize(this);
 }).on('autosize:resized', function(){
   updateSwiper();
 });
```

Solved my problem, thanks all.